# How to detect or change the language in Whisper when used in Elixir Bumblebee

Tags: elixir, openai-whisper

I started playing around with [Bumblebee](https://github.com/elixir-nx/bumblebee) in Elixir and used Whisper for speech to text processing. It works well, but I didn't find any way to detect the input language or change the languagee. So at the moment I am limited to English.

Does anyone have a solution for that? The documentation got me nowhere.

Thanks

```
# Very basic example
    {:ok, model_info} = Bumblebee.load_model({:hf, "openai/whisper-medium"})
    {:ok, featurizer} = Bumblebee.load_featurizer({:hf, "openai/whisper-medium"})
    {:ok, tokenizer} = Bumblebee.load_tokenizer({:hf, "openai/whisper-medium"})
    {:ok, generation_config} = Bumblebee.load_generation_config({:hf, "openai/whisper-medium"})

    serving =
      Bumblebee.Audio.speech_to_text(model_info, featurizer, tokenizer, generation_config,
        compile: [batch_size: 10],
        defn_options: [compiler: EXLA]
      )

# And then
    audio = Nx.from_binary(binary, :f32)

    task =
      Task.async(fn -> Nx.Serving.batched_run(WonderJournalPlayground.WhisperTask, audio) end)
```

Comment: For anyone looking at the same issue this conversation on GitHub could help: https://github.com/elixir-nx/bumblebee/pull/193

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that since Bumblebee uses the HuggingFace model of Whisper, there are a couple of limitations.

First, you must manually set the source language (no automatic input language detection has yet been implemented). And secondly, no automatic chunking is applied, which means you cannot transcribe content larger than 30 seconds.

Setting the source language isn't very straightforward. [This discussion](https://github.com/elixir-nx/bumblebee/pull/193) on GitHub provides some direction.

Example from Github:

```
defp serving do
  {:ok, whisper} = Bumblebee.load_model({:hf, "openai/whisper-small"})
  {:ok, featurizer} = Bumblebee.load_featurizer({:hf, "openai/whisper-small"})
  {:ok, tokenizer} = Bumblebee.load_tokenizer({:hf, "openai/whisper-small"})

  Bumblebee.Audio.speech_to_text(whisper, featurizer, tokenizer,
    max_new_tokens: 100,
    defn_options: [compiler: EXLA],
    forced_token_ids: [
      {1, 50267}, # %{"languages" => [{50259, en}, {50262, es}, {50267, pt}]}
      {2, 50359}, # %{"modes" => [{50358, translate}, {50359, transcribe}]}
      {3, 50363}  # %{"opts" => [{50363, notimestamps}]}
    ]
  )
end
```

When I used the large Whisper model with Bumblebee and tried transcribing German, it automatically translated it to English. So it is working somehow... But if you want to use the complete set of features Whisper has to offer and deal with multiple languages, the best way is still to use the Python model.